# Adding value in a registry key

Tags: c, batch-file, cmd, registry

I just added one registry key using:

`system("REG ADD HKLM\\Software\\DCMR__ /v PCID /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d VALUE_HERE");`
Which was successful and it added a registry key `"DCMR__"` in `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node` with the value which name is `PCID` and value `VALUE_HERE`

However if I use the same command after that, to add second value in the existing key,
using different name and value, it asks me to overwrite `PCID` because it still exists.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Make public that failing command as well, please.

Comment: Why are you using a system command to do this, when you could use a native WinAPI method? (And probably get a better error description.)

Answer (score 0):

Add `/f` option:

`REG ADD HKLM\\Software\\DCMR__ /v PCID /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d VALUE_HERE /f`